# Google Compute committed use discount

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to purchase Google Compute committed use discount for one year and for that I have requested and increased the quota for CPU's and Commitments for the required regions as described in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#purchasecommitment . All the changes are already in place but still I am not able to purchase the commitments. If I check committed CPU's for us-east1 region from quota's it is greater than 24.
Am I missing anything?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Dps.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm working for Google Cloud Support

I've checked your quota increase request,I've noticed that the committed cpu quota were granted before than the CPU quota request.
This means that your commitments is based on your previous cpu quota (24).Since the commitments will not be update by its self with the new cpu quota (greater than 24) you should then file a new commitments request in order to use your new cpu quotas.

Comment: Thanks for the update, will try submitting new commitment quota request. I had submitted CPU increase request first than commitments but they were approved in reverse order :)

Comment: Thanks this is resolved now, requested new quota upgrade and was not able to put a purchase request for commitments.